# Iterating values using Object.Keys

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate through vales of properties of an object.
here is my code

```
var player =
{

    name: 'kaka',
    age: 33,
    address: '22 green street',
    sayHello: function () {
        console.log('my name is ' + this.name + "my age is " + this.age);
    }
}

var myProperties = Object.keys(player);

for (var i = 0; i < myProperties.length; i++) {
    console.log(myProperties[i]);

}
```

But it only displays the properties and not values.
How can i go through values like `'kaka' for name..`
Thanks.

Comment: Why not doing `for (var key in player) { var value = player[key]; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the keys as lookup in original object

```
for (var i = 0; i < myProperties.length; i++) {
    if(typeof player[myProperties[i]] !== 'function'){
            console.log(player[myProperties[i]]); 
    }  
}
```

In the end I'm not sure you gain much creating and iterating the keys vs using a `for in` loop for this use case

Comment: Please tell me how it is done as i am a newbie. I mean player[myProperties[i]] .. why we use square brackets?

Comment: could do this same thing using `for(var key in player){ console.log(player[key]}` ...the `[]` are needed for variable property names

Comment: The benefit is that *Object.keys* only returns own enumerable properties of the object, whereas *for..in* returns all enumerable properties, including those on the `[[Prototype]]` chain.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since *Object.keys* returns an Array, you can use an iterator like *forEach* for convenience:

```
Object.keys(player).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key + ': ' + player[key]);
});
```